# How to find a limit of this sequence?

Tags: limits

Could you explain it step by step?

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n^2+6n+2}-\sqrt{n^2+2}}{\sqrt{9n^2+n}-\sqrt{9n^2-n}}
$$

Comment: I tried to multiply this sequence by
$$
\frac{\sqrt{9n^2+n}+\sqrt{9n^2-n}}{\sqrt{9n^2+n}+\sqrt{9n^2-n}}
$$

Comment: That's a good start, since that will 'rationalize' the denominator (the denominator will be $2n$ after the dust clears).  You'll have a mess on the top, but you should be able to expand it all out, then factor out a $2n$ to cancel the denominator, and see what's left when $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n^2+6n+2}-\sqrt{n^2+2}}{\sqrt{9n^2+n}-\sqrt{9n^2-n}}\\
=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{\sqrt{n^2+6n+2}-\sqrt{n^2+2}}{\sqrt{9n^2+n}-\sqrt{9n^2-n}} \times \frac{\sqrt{9n^2+n}+\sqrt{9n^2-n}}{\sqrt{9n^2+n}+\sqrt{9n^2-n}}  \times \frac{\sqrt{n^2+6n+2}+\sqrt{n^2+2}}{\sqrt{n^2+6n+2}+\sqrt{n^2+2}} \right)\\
= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{6n}{2n} \frac{\sqrt{9n^2+n}+\sqrt{9n^2-n}}{\sqrt{n^2+6n+2}+\sqrt{n^2+2}}\\
= \lim_{n \to \infty}3 \frac{n\left(\sqrt{9+\frac{1}{n}}+\sqrt{9-\frac{1}{n}}\right)}{n\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{6}{n}+\frac{2}{n^2}}+\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{n^2}}\right)} \\
=3\times \frac{6}{2}\\
=9
$$

Answer (score 1):

- Put $n = \infty $. We get the form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$. Lame! We need to do something else. We know that $\frac{n}{\infty} = 0$. How can I use this fact?
- Divide each term by $n^2$ (why not with $n^3$?).
- Expression becomes $\frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{6}{n}+\frac{2}{n^2}}-\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{n^2}}}{\sqrt{9+\frac{1}{n}}-\sqrt{9-\frac{1}{n}}}$.
- Let's put $n \rightarrow \infty$. We get $\frac{1-1}{3-3}$ i.e. $0/0$.
- Lame!
- I need to do something else. What if I somehow remove 0 from denominator? What can I do when I see an expression of form $a-b$ in denominator. Wait! I can multiply it with $a+b$. So multiply both numerator and denominator with a suitable term and repeat the process. Hopefully, there won't be any zero in the denominator.
- If result is 'lame' again. I am out of ideas!